# How to use self-hosted git server as production server?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm developing a website, and using my own laptop as development server, while using my online server as the production server. And I'm using git to manage my project.

I've used heroku before, and I think publishing my website simply using `git push heroku master` is really cool, so I plan to build one my self.

So, here's what I've done, I've setup git on my production server (with gitosis to manage the access), and on my git repo, I've used `git remote add git@production:myrepo.git` to add the remote for git repo.

The question is how to grab the code on production server? The production server serves as a git server, so I can only get .git folder rather than the real code. I've thought of a trick, that is use `git clone --local myrepo.git myrepo` to clone the data on the production server, and in the hooks/ folder of myrepo.git, I edited the `post-receive` file as following:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/do-we-got-here
cd /path/to/clone/myrepo
/usr/bin/git pull
```

After I use `git push production master`, the `do-we-got-here` file got created, so I can tell the post-receive hook is working, but the `git pull` part does not work, when I get to the myrepo folder, and use `git pull`, it's still pulling from myrepo.git.

So I'm wondering how to handler this? I know this is possible because hosting sites like heroku are working! But the questione is how?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: And why not to have the whole repository (with the files) in the production server? In a Distributed Version Control System there's no Repo-Server concept

Comment: @roko, nope, I don't konw how to log for hook..

Comment: @iberbeu how to get the whole files in the .git folder? I guess they are packed in the .git folder, and only git client can unpack them?

Comment: you probably created it as a mirror, so the files are not there. If you clone it as usual `git clone repo_url` you will have everything there, also the files

Comment: @iberbeu, I know, cloning the repo will get the files, but in the myrepo.git folder, there is nothing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem, this is what helped me.

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/do-we-got-here
cd /path/to/clone/myrepo
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
```

When running git hook, GIT_DIR is set. That means your pull won't run with the second repository in the directory you changed to.